# How to guarantee Model consistency when using a Database Read/Write cluster in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, concurrency

We have a database cluster setup with multiple read database hosts and a single database write host.

If we update a Laravel model, it's written immediately to the write host, then there's a small delay before that data is propagated from the write host to the read hosts.

If we do a read on the model again is uses the read databases, so within a certain amount of time while the data is propagating, the read is not guaranteed that we're getting the updated data.

Is there a solved way that we can guarantee that update has propagated to the Read only hosts before doing a Read again?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same thing.

Basically what I decided was the only way to easily handle this is add two database connections for the same database, one using the cluster endpoint (which automatically directs writes to the master and reads to the slave) and another that specifically uses the writer endpoint.

Then with your situation of hot reloading (e.g. `$model->save()->fresh()`) don't do it that way, rather, `$model->save()` and then `Model::connection('writer')->where()->first()` to reload it.

Comment: The issue I'm still having is failover. If the cluster failsover from reader to writer then you either have to change the DNS of the writer or change the DNS in the code.

Answer (score 0):

What database engine do you have and why you do that?

If it is a master-slave-configuration of MySQL, then I would try to proxy all the queries through: http://www.proxysql.com/

Comment: That looks great. We're using AWS RDS.  Is there anyway to integrate that?

Comment: I would use MySQL on a EC2, then you have the flexibility. :)